# How to do event driven programming in ASP.Net core

Tags: c#, razor

First I am new to web designing & asp.net core.

I have three components. Div component, Textbox component & Result component.see pic1

[pic-1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pD7oM.png)

What I want achieve is When I click “Div component” I want to pass value (02) from div to textbox.
Also based on change in textbox component, Result component to be updated.
Also I need put results to a table over & over (continuously)
Which technologies I should use to achieve this & if it’s possible to give me some code.

Comment: What have you tried so far with a code example?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, you might want to read [ask] and [mcve]